Are quantum advantages all about storing different weighted states with few qubits?
Consider pretty simple case of 2-qubit system (number of qubits $N=2$), which can be described as follows:
$$ |system\rangle = c_0|00\rangle+c_1|01\rangle+c_2|10\rangle+c_3|11\rangle,$$
as I understand such system is described by $2^N$ complex numbers $c_i$ (but here on page 4 it is stated, that quantum system can be described by $2^N-1$ complex numbers, which is unclear to me).
What is the power of quantum computations in this case (and in general)? Am I right, it is all about the possibility of storing different weighted states (like $c_i|01\rangle$, where $c_i$ is arbitrary complex number) with just 2 qubits?
The classical bits can also have $00$, $01$, $10$ and $11$ states for which we need only $2$ bits (for qubits we also can prepare and readout just one of the abovementioned states), so where is the advantage of quantum computations?
Maybe, I also can't see the difference, because I dont' exactly now how the classical computer bits operate in detail...

Various versions of this question have been asked many times on this site. I like, e.g., this one.  As to your confusion about why we only need $2^N-1$ complex numbers to describe a (pure) state on $N$ qubits, as the footnote in the linked thesis explains, "[n]ormalization and the irrelevance of the global phase reduce the parameter count by $2$ real numbers, or equivalently one complex number."

@MarkSpinelli, thank you for your comment, but this footnote in the thesis does tell me nothing, it is still unclear, why the author used $2^N-1$  instead of $2^N$ complex numbers (that's why I'm here and asking this question:))

In a classical computation, you start in one basis state, say $|00\rangle$, all the computational steps that you take map one basis state to another basis state, and the point of the computation is to find out which basis state you end up in.
In a quantum computation, you start in one basis state, do some operations, and the goal of the computation is to find out which basis state you end up in (ideally, you will end up in just one). As you've said, the difference is that the intermediate paths can include superposition. This gives the potential to take different routes from start to finish, which could be shorter (you can always still take the classical path, if you wish). So you can certainly see the availability of superposition as giving you the potential for some shorter path, and hence some advantage. The real question is how do we identify if there's a speed-up for any specific problem, and while there are many necessary conditions, the simple answer is we really don't know (although there's a similar lack of knowledge in classical computing about how hard different problems are).

thank you so much for your answer!) am I right, the main keynote in your answer is the following: for classical as well for quantum computer we start from one basis, do some operations and end up in some basis, and the main difference is that for quantum computer we have the property of superposition, which allows us to do these operations faster than for classical one? is it possible to give some examples?
btw, I'm not afraid of downvotes, I asked my question as much as I understand this question) I very appreciate every answer)

I'm trying to be more careful with my wording then "which allows is to do these operations faster than for classical one" because that makes it sound like there's automatically a speed-up available. All I'm saying is that it gives you different possible paths to choose from. Sometimes (often?), the classical path is still the shortest

yes, sure, I think I got it correctly about the possible paths for quantum computer) but, am I right, now you want to say, that in some cases the classical path is shorter?

Just that the classical path can be the shortest path in some cases. But a quantum computer can always follow the classical path so it's never that the classical computation is faster than the best quantum computation.

As to why a pure state on $N$ qubits can be described with only $2^N-1$ complex numbers rather than $2^N$ complex numbers, yes we generally say the dimension of an $N$-qubit system is $2^N$, but note:

every complex number can be described with two real numbers $x+iy$ with $x,y\in \mathbb R$;
a pure state requires that the sum of the squared absolute values of the amplitude is $1$ - this is the normalization requirement - so we lose one (real) degree of freedom; and
the global phase can always be ignored, so we lose another (real) degree of freedom.

Because we lose two real degrees of freedom, we lose one (complex) degree of freedom and we can subtract $1$ from the number of complex amplitudes required to describe our state.
Think of how many real numbers it takes to describe a single pure qubit $|\psi\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ when we also require $\vert \alpha\vert^2+\vert \beta\vert^2=1$.

thank you for your answer!) why do we loose two degrees of freedom? for example, I have 2 complex numbers $\alpha=x_1+y_1i$ and $\beta=x_2+y_2i$, where do I lose the degree of freedom, when I try to apply normalization condition? for $x_1^2+y_1^2+x_2^2+y_2^2 = 1$ I think I can find some real numbers for $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ to satisfy normalization condition.
